# Concatenate the .po files into a single .po file

Tags: localization, gettext

i have to concatenate following two .PO files

firstfile.po

```
msgid "Select game"
msgstr "Choisissez le jeu"


msgid "Without answers1"
msgstr "Guide d'achat1"
```

secondfile.po

```
msgid "Select game"
msgstr "Choose category"


msgid "any one answer"
msgstr "Guide d'achat
```

Here while i concating using `msgcat` without using `--use-first` the output po obtained is given below.

output.po

```
msgid "Select game"
msgstr "Choisissez le jeu"


msgid "Without answers1"
msgstr "Guide d'achat1


msgid "any one answer"
msgstr "Guide d'achat
```

Thev above output  file doesnot contain all the msgstrs found for the repeated msgid.

expected output is

output.po

```
msgid "Select game"
msgstr "Choisissez le jeu"


msgid "Without answers1"
msgstr "Guide d'achat1"

msgid "Select game"
msgstr "Choose category"


msgid "any one answer"
msgstr "Guide d'achat
```

Is there any way to repeat the same `msgid` in the output PO file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use such comand `copy firstfile.po+secondfile.po output.po`

Comment: Did you mean `cat firstfile.po secondfile.po > output.po` ?